# Make div on top of div responsive together

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a project where I'm superimposing mobile app mockups (.jpg within a scrollable div) on top of a mobile device (div with background img). I cannot figure out how to to fit the mockup within the area of the device screen in a way where both the device and mockup scale together based on viewport height (vh).

It'll make more sense when you view the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chriseddie/yt2adq16/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="device">

  <div class="screen">
    <img class="screen-display" src="http://chriseddie.com/stack/sample.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.device {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url("http://chriseddie.com/stack/apple-iphone-7-silver.jpg");
}

.screen {
  height: 70vh;
  width: 25%;
  padding-left: 1px;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.screen-display {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're scaling the device and the screen div's height by the viewport height, you need to also scale screen's width the same way. The problem you're having is that you've switched to %. You also need to do the same with the screen's top margin, instead of using a fixed value. Try changing these:

```
.screen {
  width: 40vh;
  margin-top: 15vh;
}
```

Comment: As soon as I read your response it made so much sense to me! Thanks very much that fixed my issue.